# Check upload and download speed to and from Artifactory using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, artifactory

I am using an [Artifactory library](https://pypi.org/project/artifactory/) to upload and download files with Python.

```py
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath
path = ArtifactoryPath(
    "http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/distributions/org/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.11.tar.gz")

with path.open() as fd:
    with open("tomcat.tar.gz", "wb") as out:
        out.write(fd.read())
```

However, I would also want to know the upload and download speed.

How can I do that apart from just dividing it by the duration. ?
Any other better way to fetch speed?
Any other module which can give the speed details to/from Artifactory.

Comment: Divide the amount of data by the upload or download duration.

Comment: I think your question can be resuscitated (closed for not focused), so I made some hefty, but very generalized edits to your question, which will allow it to be re-opened via a queue. If you don't agree with my edits, you can revert them! Otherwise, please edit your question with further details (such as an example from your code). It can then be re-opened via a queue.

Comment: It's largely easier to help and to help future readers with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Structuring your question this way really helps it get more attention and avoid premature closure.

Answer (score 1):

You could time the transaction and divide the size of the downloaded file by the period.

```py
import time

from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath

path = ArtifactoryPath("http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/distributions/org/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.11.tar.gz")

time_start = time.time()
with path.open() as f_artifactory:
    with open("tomcat.tar.gz", "wb") as fh_out:
        fh_out.write(f_artifactory.read())
        written_len = fh_out.tell()  # position in a binary file is its size in bytes

time_end = time.time()
rate = written_len / (time_end - time_start)  # in bytes / second
print("speed: {} MB/s".format(rate / (10**6))  # example MB conversion
```

ArtifactoryPath usage adapted from https://pypi.org/project/artifactory/